# Flot Pie Chart - Breaking on 1 data item

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, flot

I am having a strange issue with trying to get my Flot pie charts to show up when there is only one data item, or only one data-item that has a non-zero value. Everything works fine with multiple data items, however when there is only one non-zero item left (where the pie chart should show 100%), the chart just breaks. I have a longer file where I found out about this problem, but it is also happening with some simple code. I looked at [this](http://www.pureexample.com/jquery-flot/pie-chart.html) link and modified that code to work how I want it to, but upon moving it into my code it didn't work for me.

```
<div class='col-md-4'>
    <div class='panel panel-default'>
        <div class='panel-heading'>
            Volunteer Hour Completion
        </div>
        <div class='panel-body'>
                <div class="flot-chart">
                    <div class="flot-chart-content" id="flotcontainer"></div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var data = [
        {label: "data1", data:10},
        {label: "data2", data: 20},
        {label: "data3", data: 20}
    ];

    var options = {
            series: {
                pie: {show: true}
            }
         };

    $.plot($("#flotcontainer"), data, options);
});
```

When I change data2 and data3 to 0 (or just remove those items), the chart breaks and I don't see data1 showing up as 100% percent as I should.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: [Works fine for me.](http://plnkr.co/edit/aXGXcRIwh2oH8GFnPvrA?p=preview)  Any errors on your console?

Comment: Like Mark said, you should check your console for errors. If you don't find any, make sure you are using the latest version of the flot library and pie-chart plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the latest versions of jquery.js, jquery.flot.js and jquery.flot.pie.js?
Try placing your javascript code above html.

Comment: That was it. The version I was using was one or two small releases behind, which caused this issue for whatever reason.